# Find the limit $\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}\frac{x\sin(y)}{x^2+\sin^2(y)} $

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits

Consider the limit 
$$\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0) }\frac{x\sin(y)}{x^2+\sin^2(y)} $$
I thought the limit does not exist, but plotting by software showed the limit should be 0. I’ve tried squeeze and episilon-delta proof, but haven’t make any progress yet. Any hint or help are appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

let $x=k\sin y$, than the given fraction is equal to $\frac k {k^2+1}$. Since $x$ is independent to $y$ we know that the given limit diverging.